# Replace arbitrary characters that are not part of an HTML tag

Tags: php, parsing

I am developing a simple text parser that parses certain markup commands. One of these commands is to apply highlighting to a PHP string. I do this using the highlight_string() function.

Because of the way my parser works, commands are parsed consecutively, with highlighting being one of the first things parsed, but this poses a problem: I do not want to apply markup to the highlighted string anymore. The way I am doing that for other commands is by simply escaping characters that are part of any command, but I cannot do that here, since it would also escape some characters in the already generated HTML (for instance, "/", would be escaped).

Basically, my question is: "How can I escape certain characters (not "<" or ">") from a string containing HTML, without escaping any characters that are part of the HTML itself?".

I have already tried using PHP's built in XML parser, but this results in an error:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
```

Comment: Telepathy offline, please post actual code and example data.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to give an example how the file you want to parse looks like.
Anyway I'd say that you could use an Boolean as a flag to indicate whether you are in HTML or PHP code.

If there was an an `<?php` somewhere and you didn't find a `?>` then you are in PHP-Code and your flag that could be named *isPHP* would then be `true` and otherwise it would be `false`.

If your text contains the edge case that your PHP-Code has a String somewhere  which contains valid HTML-Code, then you'd better be of with a stack of booleans as flags.